# Could not find file 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\file.xlsx'

Tags: c#, openxml

I have been struggling with this for a while now, I am running out of ideas.
I have a MVC application which utilized Open XML to upload excel files. Everything works fine on my local machine, but as soon as I deploy it it doesn't seem to work and throws the above exception. I have given permissions of the folder to user running in IIS to user(Network Service), but still get the above error. Please see my code below and advice,

```
try
        {
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                string path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                file.SaveAs(path);
```

Comment: getting the obvious question out of the way first - is the file in the specified folder?

Comment: No, its not, I am attempting to save it to the the location. As different users will be uploading files with the app.

Comment: does the exception occur on `file.SaveAs` or `Path.Combine` ?

Comment: A relative path is used in the `Path.Combine`. Are you sure it resolves to what you expect? An absolute path would be safer. Otherwise, please look at the contents of variable `file` and post that here.

Comment: @user1666620 it occurs on file.SaveAs() function